# How can i navigate between different pages using vue router?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have just started learning `Vue`. I actually became confused with the `Vue router` part. It's a very simple question. I tried looking for many docs and tuts but didn't find anything that I was looking for. It might be my fault on not implementing them correctly which I can understand as a beginner but still got stuck. Let me explain what I am trying to obtain and what I did so far.

This is my `Home.vue` file and I want user to see this page by default on `/` path.

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <MainNavigation />
        <LandingSection />
        <Services />
        <WhyKontext />
        <SignupTrial />
        <Footer />
    </div>
</template>
```

This is my code for `App.vue`

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <Home />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Home from "./views/landing/Home";
    export default {
        name: "App",
        components: {
            Home,
        },
    };
</script>
```

This is my `router.js`

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import LoginRegister from "./views/account/LoginRegister";
import App from "./App";
Vue.use(VueRouter);

export default new VueRouter({
    mode: "history",
    routes: [
    {
        path: "/",
        component: App,
    },
    {
        path: "/account",
        component: LoginRegister,
    },
    ],
});
```

On `MainNavigation.vue` there is this block of code

```html
<router-link to="/account" class="bg-color text-white">TRY CONTEXT </router-link>
```

What I am trying is: If a user clicks on **TRY KONTEXT** button, I want them to go to Signup/Login page named as `LoginRegister.vue`.
I tried by putting  `<router-view></router-view>` on `MainNavigation` but `LoginRegister` page comes attached with the rest of the `Home` components. When I am on `http://localhost:8080/` then I get complete `Home`. When I click on **TRY KONTEXT** button It takes me to `http://localhost:8080/account` but I still can see All the `Home` Components along with `LoginRegister`. I am trying to make `MainNavigation` and `Footer` at all pages and Just change the content at middle according to the route. In this case, I actually wanted to see `MainNavigation`, `LoginRegister` and `Footer`. I know it's a silly question. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your `router-view` in your `App.vue`, with the basic layout in it, such as header/footer/side_bar. Now, your App.vue should contain something like this:

```html
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <AppHeader></AppHeader>
        <router-view/>
        <AppFooter></AppFooter>
    </div>
</template>
```

Then move your `Home.vue` to a separate file, so that it doesn't contain header and footer which you already included in your layout:

```html
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <carousel></carousel>
        <image-grid></image-grid>
    </div>
</template>
```

Now, in your `router.js`, specify the routes, almost like this:

```js
import Home from './path/to/home.vue'
routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'home',
        component: Home
    }
]
```

Comment: Hello Muhammadrasul , Can you please check this [GIST](https://gist.github.com/20was/a9f2b374a223617dd295d83979398f55)  , I am getting `/account` page correct but on `/` route it shows me 2 nav bar and 2 footer.

Comment: yeah, just remove navbar and footer from your home.vue, coz it is already in layout, and you don't need to add them in every page

Comment: Yes. I already removed it. You can check my corrected code on Gist.

Comment: and does it work properly now? I cannot run gist if you know

Comment: and why do all your component files have `.js` extension?

Comment: That's what I told. It shows me 2 navigation bar and 2 footer on `http://localhost:8080/` , but works fine for `/account`. `.js` is for syntax highlighting for gist, it didn't work with .vue extension.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218232/discussion-between-bishwas-and-muhammadrasul).

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your `App.vue` component template like this:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <router-view/>
    </div>
</template>
```

The logic behind this is that the app is showing the current selection of your router.